# Magento VAT Number Invalid

Tags: vat

Magento return 'VAT Number is Invalid' every time event I entered valid VAT Number.

[image]

I checked my VAT number [here](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/) and it's working I got all information with my name. please help why Magento return Invalid.

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: You must input the VAT number without the country prefix.

Comment: yes i entered VAT number without country prefix like my VAT number is CZ42555751 and I entered 42555751.

Comment: Hm ok. The number you just gave me wasn't the real one I assume? Which Magento version are you using?

Comment: i used Magento ver. 1.9.0.1